# como puedo centrar este menu de navegacion

Tags: css

Soy principiante y estoy intentado alinear este menú de navegación, aquí les dejo el código. Es un código en css, el problema es que no se como alinearlo a centro:

```
h1{
   font-family: verdana;
   text-align: center;
   background: url(images.jpg);
   height: 50px;
   color: white;
  }


 .enlaces{
   display: inline-block;
   background: #34c6eb;
   color: #fff;
   padding: 10px 30px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: Sería genial que pudieras compartir el HTML.

Comment: Lo ideal seria que compartas el codigo html, ya que lo que vos necesitas posicionar elementos, y la posicion de un elemento puede hacerse en relacion a otros elementos (o no), entonces habria que ver como estan los elementos en el html, para darte una ayuda mas exacta

Comment: ok ya lo comparto

Comment: Una vez que añadas el html te podria apoyar porque se me ocurren muchas formas de hacerlo pero todo depende de como este acomodado todo tu html en estructura.

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende muy bien la pregunta debido a la falta de informacion de codigo
Te recomiendo que seas mas claro y tambien subir el codigo html

Bueno intuyo que quieres alinear una lista de navegacion y enlaces , el codigo es el siguiente

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sección</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Otra sección</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">La tercera sección</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Última sección</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Y en los estilos CSS es lo siguiente

```css
ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li a {
  padding: 10px;
  /* Añadirá separación entre los elementos */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```